# jquery scrollbar plugin conflicts with jquery pagination plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, scrollbar

first time asking a question here, so thank you in advance and please excuse me if I violate any rules. I'm trying to use this jquery pagination plugin from this site:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-easy-pagination-with-jquery/

and some how it's just not working with the jquery scrollbar plugin I'm using, which is from here:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Here's the code I'm working with, you'll see that the scrollbar plugin works on the first page, but after you click on any other subsequent pages it no longer functions:

```js
var Imtech = {};
Imtech.Pager = function() {
    this.paragraphsPerPage = 3;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pagingControlsContainer = '#pagingControls';
    this.pagingContainerPath = '#content';

    this.numPages = function() {
        var numPages = 0;
        if (this.paragraphs != null && this.paragraphsPerPage != null) {
            numPages = Math.ceil(this.paragraphs.length / this.paragraphsPerPage);
        }
        
        return numPages;
    };

    this.showPage = function(page) {
        this.currentPage = page;
        var html = '';

        this.paragraphs.slice((page-1) * this.paragraphsPerPage,
            ((page-1)*this.paragraphsPerPage) + this.paragraphsPerPage).each(function() {
            html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
        });

        $(this.pagingContainerPath).html(html);

        renderControls(this.pagingControlsContainer, this.currentPage, this.numPages());
    }

    var renderControls = function(container, currentPage, numPages) {
        var pagingControls = 'Page: <ul>';
        for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
            if (i != currentPage) {
                pagingControls += '<li><a href="#" onclick="pager.showPage(' + i + '); return false;">' + i + '</a></li>';
            } else {
                pagingControls += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
            }
        }

        pagingControls += '</ul>';

        $(container).html(pagingControls);
    }
}
```

```css
.scroll_container {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}
.example {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 1000px;
  font-size: 80%;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  margin: 0.5em 10% 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 2em 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px
}
#content p {
  text-indent: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
#pagingControls ul {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0.5em
}
#pagingControls li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0.5em
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/imtech_pager.js"></script>
<!-- Add jquery scrollbar plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin-master/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<script src="assets/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin-master/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Deals</h1>
        <div id="content" class="scroll_container scroll">
          <div class="z">
            Sergey LUKYANENKO - The Boy and the Darkness - Chapter 1. The Sun Kitten.
            <h3>Xmas Special Menu</h3>
            <div class="button">
              Read More
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            Everything happened because I got ill.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            It was already two in the afternoon, and I was lying in bed flicking through "Peter Pan" - I must have read it a hundred times over. I had long since pulled off the bandage my mother had tied around my neck in the morning, and thrown it into a corner. I simply can't understand - how can cotton wool soaked in vodka possibly help a cough? I don't argue with my mum, of course, but after she leaves I look after myself in my own way - namely, lie in bed with a book and wait for my germs to get tired of such a boring method of passing time. It usually helps - perhaps not at once, but after a day or three. A good thing, really, that the street outside looked quite miserable - the sun poking out for brief moments, only to make room for a patchy, nasty drizzle. Though, the sun never actually peeked into the room - our house is so unfortunately placed that it is in the shadows of the new nine-floor high-rises on every side. "The only use for such a flat is to grow mushrooms", - dad used to say, back when he still lived with us.
            <div>
              testing testing testing
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            I put my book down on the floor next to the bed, and lay on my back. Perhaps, had I shut my eyes now, nothing would have happened. But there I was, lying staring at the ceiling and listening to the ticking of the clock in the hallway.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            And a speck of sunlight jumped into the room through the glass. Small - the size of my hand - but surprisingly bright. As though the window was open, with bright summer sun outside. Someone was probably playing with a mirror on the balcony of the house across the street.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            The rabbit floated across the ceiling, climbed down a wall, made a vase on the dressing-table glint, and stopped, shaking slightly, on my headrest.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Don't go, - I said for some reason, knowing that in a moment the mirror would shift and the rabbit would leave my room forever. - Stay...
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            And that's when it all started.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            The sun rabbit tore free of the bed and floated in the air. I didn't even realise at first that such things don't happen. It was only when the flat spot hanging in the air started puffing out to form a fuzzy orange ball that I understood - a miracle had happened.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            Four paws stretched from orange glowing fur, followed by a tail and a head. Green cat eyes blinked and gazed at me steadily. And overall, in fact, the rabbit looked more like a kitten than anything else. Except he was hanging in the air, glowing, and seemed light as the fairy fluff that floats away if one blows gently.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Hello, - purred the kitten. - Thank you for the invitation.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            I closed my eyes for a second, but when I opened them again, the kitten hadn't disappeared. In fact, he'd flown closer.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - I don't believe in fairy tales, - I told myself. - I'm grown up now.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Well, compared to the girl who was holding the True Mirror, you are quite grown up, - declared the kitten, unperturbed, and lowered himself onto the blanket. I glanced over - to see if there would be smoke - but everything seemed all right. I could feel warmth with my chest, but not strong. And the kitten tilted his head and added: - But one can't really call you adult, either. How old are you? Ten, maybe?
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Fourteen, - I replied, finding myself calming down at such a mundane question. - Who're you?
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - A sun rabbit, - replied the kitten, examining himself curiously. - What an appearance.. do I look like one?
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - <b>Like</b> what?
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Like a
            <p style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">sun</p>
            rabbit.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - More like a kitten.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Hardly better, - stated the Kitten sadly and stretched out. And I didn't think of anything better than repeating:
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - Who're you?
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - But we have already arrived at a consensus! - said the Kitten with sudden hurt. - A sun rabbit, or more precisely - a kitten, because I look far more like one! What is there not to understand?
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            I found myself tongue-tied. Well, naturally, a small green animal that eats stones would simply be - a small green stone-eater. Simple. And a sun rabbit is a sun kitten, because he looks nothing like a rabbit.
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - So you mean - any rabbit can come to life if one just calls it? - I asked cautiously. For some reason it seemed to me the Kitten would be hurt at the question again. But he just shook his head proudly:
          </div>
          <div class="z">
            - As if! Any! Only True Light, reflected in a True Mirror, can come to life.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pagingControls">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pager = new Imtech.Pager();
$(document).ready(function() {
    pager.paragraphsPerPage = 5; // set amount elements per page
    pager.pagingContainer = $('#content'); // set of main container
    pager.paragraphs = $('div.z', pager.pagingContainer); // set of required containers
    pager.showPage(1);
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable=true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
 $(".scroll").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"light-2"}); //I have modified the theme light-2
  $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this=$(this),
      rel=$this.attr("rel"),
      el=$(".content");
     switch(rel){
      case "toggle-content":
       el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
       break;
     }
 });
});
</script>
</html>
```

The rest is the files from the malihu jquery-custom-content-scroller

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the #content div within a new div and add the 'scroll_container' class to that. That should work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/heq8bgnb/2/)

```
<div class="example">
    <h3><a href="#">Paragraph pagination sample</a></h3>
    <div class="scroll_container">
<div id="content">
        <div class="z">Sergey LUKYANENKO - The Boy and the Darkness - Chapter 1. The Sun Kitten.</div>
        .....
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pagingControls"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow that worked great, so is it that when both those classes are on the same div they clash?